# Could not locate entry in sysdatabases for database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need this code to run the instant the professor hits the F5 button.

**I created a database and I have a problem with the USE statement**

SQL just can't switch to the database that USE statement is calling. it's saying this:

> could not locate entry in sysdatabases for database

I tried with square brackets ([]) and it's not helping.
The project is about Car Service and its a school project.
I just need that USE statement to run or some other solution so the code can run without error and in one click on **F5**.

```
USE master;  
IF DB_ID('ServisAutomobila') IS NOT NULL  
DROP DATABASE ServisAutomobila; 
GO

CREATE DATABASE ServisAutomobila;

USE ServisAutomobila

go

CREATE TABLE Automobil 
(
    Automobil_ID int identity (1,1) not null,
    Model nvarchar (50) not null,
    GodinaProizvodnje nvarchar(50) not null,
    RegistarskiBroj nvarchar (50) unique not null,
    BrojMotora nvarchar (50) unique not null,
    BrojSasije nvarchar (50) unique not null,
    Kvar nvarchar (250) not null,
    TipAutomobila_ID int not null,
    Zemlja_ID int not null,
    Vlasnik_ID int not null
)

CREATE TABLE Zemlja
(
    Zemlja_ID int identity (1,1) not null,
    Zemlja nvarchar (50) not null
)
```

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: Have you tried to put "GO" before "USE"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - create database and tables in one script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373268/sql-create-database-and-tables-in-one-script)

Comment: Per @DaleBurrell comment, try putting a `GO` between your `CREATE DATABASE` and `USE` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GO keyword is a batch terminator. So in your example:

```
CREATE DATABASE ServisAutomobila;

USE ServisAutomobila

go
```

The batch is executed as one and results in that particular error because the database engine tries do use database ServisAutomobila which does not exists yet. This means that you **must** add that extra GO suggested in the previous comments before you can use the newly created database:

```
CREATE DATABASE ServisAutomobila;
GO;
USE ServisAutomobila;
GO;
```